# Why are the support vectors in an SVM classifier on hyperplanes that are 1 or -1 away from the wanted hyperplane

Tags: svm

The way it is described here https://www.svm-tutorial.com/2015/06/svm-understanding-math-part-3/ , the wanted hyperplane is found by finding two other hyperplanes which have the equations

$\vec{w}\vec{x}+b = 1$ and $\vec{w}\vec{x}+b = -1$.

He puts it like the values are chosen for simplicity.

In this video  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bS1avoD6g8s at 3:07 it kinda sounds like the values **have** to be 1 and -1.

I don't understand why the values are (or have to be) 1 and -1.

If I understand correctly, the margin of the wanted hyperplane is given by the other two hyperplanes going through the support vectors and each hyperplane is half a margin away from the wanted hyperplane.

Why can't the equations of the two hyperplanes be $\vec{w}\vec{x}+b = +/- 5$ or something else?

Comment: It is arbitrary, the fact that b is there makes the actual value irrelevant. You should watch this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_PwhiWxHK8o. It is the best out there in my opinion.

Comment: It is arbitrary but $b$ has nothing to do with this. See this answer: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/279450/should-the-resulting-weight-vector-of-svm-be-of-unit-length/282334#282334