# How does the ρ parameter work in this customized SVM?

Tags: machine-learning, svm

The article (https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6691771) uses a customized support vector machine with the following loss function:

[image: Loss function]

I recognize the slack variable **ξ** together with hyperparameter **C** which controls the amount of slack that is allowed. I can imagine that with smaller **C**, you allow more slack and therefore you can sacrifice a few instances in order to find a wider margin with more support vectors.

[image: Soft-margin SVM]

But how does the **ρ** work? The article mentions **ρ** controls the number of support vectors which in turn changes the number of positive predicted instances. But I don't understand why this works. Could someone please explain this to me?

[image: Explanation of ρ of the article]

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/279450/should-the-resulting-weight-vector-of-svm-be-of-unit-length/282334#282334

Comment: Thanks! This is what I'm looking for.