# Scholkopf single class linear SVM equation: why ρ substracted to 1/2 ||w||² is the same as maximizing the distance

Tags: machine-learning, optimization, svm

In the one class linear SVM, the equation is :

$\min_{w, \rho} \frac{1}{2} \|w\|^2- \rho + C\sum_{i=1}^{n} \xi_i$

subject to:

$\begin{align*}
& w \cdot x_i \geq \rho - \xi_i, \\
& \xi_i \geq 0, \\
& i = 1, 2, ..., n.
\end{align*}$

The first constraint suggests that, when x is a support vector, we have $w \cdot x = \rho$

The distance to a support vector x is $\frac{w \cdot x}{\|w\|}$, hence $\frac{\rho}{\|w\|}$

Maximizing the distance would be minimizing

$\frac{\|w\|}{\rho}$.

How does this become minimizing $\frac{1}{2} \|w\|^2 -\rho$ ?

Comment: Does this answer help you: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/279450/should-the-resulting-weight-vector-of-svm-be-of-unit-length/282334#282334

Comment: @MotiNK Hi, this answer seems to talk about the two-class problem. My question is specifically about the one-class problem. Right now I think I think the minization is a bit arbitrary in that specific case, and not equivalent to maximazing the distance.

Comment: Note that the only difference here between 1-class and 2-class is the constraint not having a $y_i$ as part of the expression. 

The margin here is relative to the origin in feature space.

In any case to quote from the article they also refer to the $||w||$ term as the "SV type regularization term".

But generally speaking there is always some balance here between margin maximization balanced against error terms. The construct here allows them to achieve the control via $\mu$ they are after in terms of the number of SVs.